# dataframe groupby to find the values of each row after groupby.size()

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 2 columns; id and item. id is the id and item is the value of the id.
1. I wish to first groupby my dataframe and then find the number of size of each id as below.
2. Then after getting the count, i wish to append the value at the back of the count by using .merge function.

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3],
                 'item':['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'total1']})
a.groupby('id').size().reset_index(name='count')
```

result:

```
    id  count
0   1   4
1   2   3
2   3   1
```

expected

```
    id  item   count
0   1   test1   4
1   1   test2   4
2   1   test3   4
3   1   test4   4
4   2   value1   3
5   2   value2   3
6   2   value3   3
7   3   total1   1
```

Comment: use transform here: `a['count']=a.groupby('id')['item'].transform('size')`

Comment: is there a way to use my method according to sequence then apply .merge? I wish to use that way instead of changing the sequence

Comment: use `a = a.merge(a.groupby('id').size().reset_index(name='count'),on='id')`